# Building a toggler in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, siblings

Im trying to build a toggler based on this one http://jsfiddle.net/Adib/fZc3L/
The problem is that i still can't find the right siblings to be toggled on click,

```
<aside class="aside">
    <div class="element">
        <header><a href="#Cat1">Categorys</a></header>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <header><a href="#Cat1">Categorys:</a></header>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="element">
        <header><a href="#Cat1">Categorys:</a></header>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Category 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Category 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</aside>
```

see the full code,
http://jsfiddle.net/Adib/PPmLe/

And thanks.

Comment: Please clearly explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Seems simple enough? [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPmLe/6/) ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear what you want to achieve, but I think it's to make sure only one category is open.  So I modified your code:

```
cat.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        section = $this.parent('header').next('section');

    // hide open categories
    $('aside section').slideUp();
    // open clicked category
    section.slideDown();
})
```

Have a look at the full solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/PPmLe/2/

**Update**

The following is how I would solve the problem, and it involves storing what section is visible so it's easy to hide that one specifically, rather than hiding all sections others than the current one:

```
$(function() {
    // hide all sections except the first
    $('.element section:not(:first)').hide();

    // store what section is visible
    var visible_section = $('.element section:first');

    $('.element header > a').click(function() {
        // hide the visible section
        visible_section.slideUp();
        // show the current section
        var section = $(this).parent().next('section');
        section.slideDown();
        // update the new visible section
        visible_section = section;
    })
});​
```

Comment: That causes the current section to slide up and down again if clicked after the first time

Comment: That's what i want, it was rather easy, thanks.

Comment: @wirey It does yeah, but I wasn't sure what was required, so I just knocked that together to see if it was the case. I shouldn't have used the word 'solution'. I would consider my latest version a solution though: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/PPmLe/10/

Answer (score 1):

Your sections aren't siblings.  You can do this

```
cat.on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        section = $this.parent('header').next('section');        
        section.slideDown();
        $('.element section').not(section).slideUp(); // all sections but current one slide up
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HVNJ2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution showing only one section.

```
$(function() {
    $("header a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("section").hide();
        $(this).parent().next("section").show();
    });

    $("section").not(".first").hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PPmLe/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this jsFiddle that I created: http://jsfiddle.net/PPmLe/8/

The main difference between your script and mine is this:

```
 $this.parents('.element').siblings().find('section').slideUp();
```

Comment: A new idea ! Thanks mate